# Command not found when I call `./myshell` in ruby

Tags: ruby, irb

Today, I tried to call a script from ruby. I did like this:

```
`./aaa.sh`,
```

but it returned 'command not found', here is the session log of irb:

```
irb(main):012:0> `which aaa.sh`
=> "/root/rocky/aaa.sh\n"
irb(main):013:0> `aaa.sh`
(irb):13: command not found: aaa.sh
=> ""
irb(main):014:0> `./aaa.sh`
(irb):14: command not found: ./aaa.sh
=> ""
```

But, if I call it as 'sh aaa.sh', it works.

```
irb(main):015:0> `sh aaa.sh`
=> "aaa.sh\ntest.rb\n"
```

so, what's wrong whith this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple possibilities immediately come to mind:

1. Your `aaa.sh` file doesn't have execute permission.
2. Your `aaa.sh` file doesn't start with `#!/bin/sh` so the OS doesn't know how to execute it.

As an aside, are you really experimenting while logged in as root? That's a quick and easy way to have a really bad day.

Comment: And, I found an interesting resolution. `./aaa.sh\n` works! why is that? my ruby is 1.8.6

Comment: @Rocky: The `\n`, like other leading and trailing whitespace, is being ignored so that's the same as `./aaa.sh`.