# Running shell scripts missing shebang within Ruby

Tags: ruby, shell

I discovered an interesting issue in Ruby whose behavior I cannot explain.

I was trying to run a shell script that had execute permission, but the shell script accidentally left out the shebang (#!) at the top that describes how to run said script.

If I try running the script within irb using backticks (`), it says:

```
>> `./hello.sh`
(irb):3: command not found: ./hello.sh
```

Fair enough.  However, if I instead type in

```
>> `./hello.sh\n`
=> "hello\n"
```

It surprisingly works.  Note that `%x{...}`'s behavior is consistent with the above (not surprising given their equivalence) but `system()` does not work, newline or not (ok by me).  Also, not surprisingly, adding back in the appropriate `#!` to the shell script (hello.sh)  makes everything work.

I tried searching for an answer, and I could only find an allusion to it in "[Command not found when I call `./myshell` in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074515/command-not-found-when-i-call-myshell-in-ruby)."  However, the reply dismisses the idea that the newline changes the semantics of the command, which it seems to do.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot recreate this issue, for me, this all works okay:

~/ echo 'echo "foobar"' > hello.sh
~/ cat hello.sh
echo "foobar"
~/ irb
1.9.3p194 :001 > `./hello.sh`
 => "foobar\n"
1.9.3p194 :002 > `./hello.sh\n`
 => "foobar\n"

Running Ruby 1.9.3, zshell, Mac OS